# Pipenv with python headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv

Is there any way to setup a virtualenv with pipenv that includes the python headers files?

My problems are that I need some libraries that needs to be built, and I need to have the python headers in my virtualenv.

Right now I'm using:

```
WORKON_HOME=.venv # setup venv in .venv
```

then I build packages as

```
./configure --prefix=`pipenv --venv`
```

That works fine, for libs that don't need to be compiled with python headers, but not for all.